# Rendering remote content through html frame !

Tags: html

I want to display remote content using html 'frame'.Say i want to display the content of www.news.google.com on a frame ...how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools has a [page explaining the basics](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp) of the `<iframe>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="http://news.google.com" height="500" width="500">
text here if iframe is unable to display
</iframe>
```

change the size values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Set `src` attribute of a `<iframe>` or `<frame>` to the URL you want to display content from.